# Скрыть токен телеграм бота

Tags: telegram-bot, angular2, telegram, token

Нужно обратиться к чатботу из Angular  приложения. Для запроса к боту нужно указать токен и Id чата. Как можно скрыть токен и id в приложении, чтобы к нему никто не могу подучить доступ, но при этом можно было обратиться к боту?

Comment: Создайте промежуточное **Api**, в котором будете принимать данные из **Angular**  и отправлять в чат **Telegram**, а само апи и доступ к нему будете иметь только вы.

Answer (score 0):

Сам ищу ответ.
На данный момент, вроде как смог (по крайней мере во вкладке network - не читается) скрыть chat_id. Поместил его в body POST запроса:

```
const url2 = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage`

const telegramBot = ajax({
    url: url2,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {

    },
    body: {
        chat_id: chatId,
        text: `Пользователь: ${userName}\n`
              `Номер телефона: ${userPhone}\n`
              `Хочет купить: ${this.router.url}\n`
              `Comments: ${userComments}`
    }

});
```

А как скрыть токен в url пути - хотелось бы тоже узнать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос. а этот «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите.